# java.lang.NullPointerException when populating Jtextfield using a bean class

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans, javabeans

Here is my class which is a gui consisting of two tabs, my profile and edit profile. I am having a problem at the 'myProfileTabStateChanged' method when the index value changes to 1. When tab index is 0, 'myProfile()' method executes successfully, but when index is 1, 'editProfile()' is giving too many errors. The purpose of editprofile() is simply to extract the values from a bean class and set it to the textfields appropriately. What am I doing wrong? Please note the bean class variables are being populated correctly using setter methods, but in this class I am unable to retrieve the values using the getters? Perhaps it is retrieving but problem lies in being unable to set it to textfield.

```
public class MainMenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Academic ac = new Academic();
    academicBean bn = new academicBean();

    /**
     * Creates new form MainMenu
     */
    public MainMenu() {
        initComponents();
        // myProfile(); 
        // editProfile(); 
    }

    public void myProfile() {
        ac.retrieveAcademic();
        nameLabel.setText(""+ac.title+" "+ac.forename+" "+ac.surname);
        roleLabel.setText("Role:    " + ac.role);
        roomLabel.setText("Room:    " + ac.room);
        pageLabel.setText("Page:    " + ac.page);
        hoursLabel.setText("Hours:   " + ac.hours);
        phoneLabel.setText("Phone:   " + ac.phone);
        mobileLabel.setText("Mobile:  " + ac.mobile);
        emailLabel.setText("Email:   " + ac.email);
        imageLabel.setIcon(ac.format);
    }

    public void editProfile() {
        ac.retrieveAcademic();
        idLabel.setText("Academic Id:    "+bn.getAcademicId());
        txt_title.setSelectedItem(bn.getTitle().toString());
        txt_fn.setText(bn.getForename().toString());
        txt_ln.setText(bn.getSurname().toString());
        combo_role.setSelectedItem(bn.getRole().toString());
        txt_room.setText(bn.getRoom().toString());
        txt_page.setText(bn.getPage().toString());
        txt_hours.setText(bn.getHours().toString());
        txt_phone.setText(bn.getPhone().toString());
        txt_mobile.setText(bn.getMobile().toString());
        txt_email.setText(bn.getEmail().toString());
    }

    private void myProfileTabStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
        JTabbedPane sourceTabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) evt.getSource();
        int index = sourceTabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();

            if (index == 0) {
            myProfile();
        }

        else if (index == 1) {
            editProfile(); 
        }
    }
```

//Class Academic

```
public class Academic extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   String filename = null;
   int s = 0;
   byte[] person_image = null;
   ImageIcon format = null;

   LoginBean l = new LoginBean();
   Connection con = javaconnect.ConnectDB();
   academicBean bean = new academicBean();

   PreparedStatement pst = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;

   int id;
   String title;
   String titleValue;
   String forename;
   String surname;
   String role;
   String roleValue;
   String room;
   String page;
   String hours;
   String phone;
   String mobile;
   String email;
   byte[] imagedata = null;

   public Academic() {
      initComponents();
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public void retrieveAcademic() {

      try {
         pst = con
               .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM AcademicInfo where Email=? and Password=?");
         pst.setString(1, l.getUsername());
         pst.setString(2, l.getPassword());
         rs = pst.executeQuery();
         while (rs.next()) {
            id = (rs.getInt(1));
            bean.setAcademicId(id);
            title = (rs.getString(2));
            bean.setTitle(title);
            forename = (rs.getString(3));
            bean.setForename(forename);
            surname = (rs.getString(4));
            bean.setSurname(surname);
            role = (rs.getString(5));
            bean.setRole(role);
            room = (rs.getString(6));
            bean.setRoom(room);
            page = (rs.getString(7));
            bean.setPage(page);
            hours = (rs.getString(8));
            bean.setHours(hours);
            phone = (rs.getString(9));
            bean.setPhone(phone);
            mobile = (rs.getString(10));
            bean.setMobile(mobile);
            email = (rs.getString(11));
            bean.setEmail(email);
            imagedata = (rs.getBytes("Image"));
            format = new ImageIcon(imagedata);

         } // end while

      } catch (SQLException ex) {
         Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Academic.class.getName());
         lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

      } finally {

         try {
            if (rs != null) {
               rs.close();
            }
            if (pst != null) {
               pst.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
               con.close();
            }

         } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Academic.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

// Bean Class

```
public class AcademicBean {

private int academicid;
private String title;
private String forename;
private String surname;
private String role;
private String room;
private String page;
private String hours;
private String phone;
private String mobile;
private String email;
private byte []  image;
private String pass; 

 //Setters

public void setAcademicId (int academicid) {
    this.academicid = academicid;
}   
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}   
public void setForename(String forename) {
    this.forename = forename;
}
public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}
public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
public void setRoom(String room) {
    this.room = room;
}
public void setPage(String page) {
    this.page = page;
}
public void setHours(String hours) {
    this.hours = hours;
}
public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
public void setMobile(String mobile) {
    this.mobile = mobile;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public void setImage (byte [] image) {

     this.image = image; 
 }
public void setPassword (String pass) {

     this.pass= pass;
 }



//Gettters 

public String getPassword () {

     return pass;  
 }

public int getAcademicId() {

     return academicid; 
 }


public byte [] getImage() {
     return image;
 }
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public String getForename() {
    return forename;
}
public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}
public String getRole() {
    return role;
}
public String getRoom() {
    return room;
}
public String getPage() {
    return page;
}
public String getHours() {
    return hours;
}
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
public String getMobile() {
    return mobile;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
}
```

//Stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.(PrepStmt.java:37)
  at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:231)
  at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:224)
  at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:213)
  at eecsCRM.Academic.retrieveAcademic(Academic.java:68)
  at eecsCRM.MainMenu.editProfile(MainMenu.java:50)
  at eecsCRM.MainMenu.myProfileTabStateChanged(MainMenu.java:569)
  at eecsCRM.MainMenu.access$300(MainMenu.java:13)
  at eecsCRM.MainMenu$4.stateChanged(MainMenu.java:194)
  at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.fireStateChanged(JTabbedPane.java:400)
  at javax.swing.JTabbedPane$ModelListener.stateChanged(JTabbedPane.java:253)
  at javax.swing.DefaultSingleSelectionModel.fireStateChanged(DefaultSingleSelectionModel.java:116)
  at javax.swing.DefaultSingleSelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(DefaultSingleSelectionModel.java:50)
  at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndexImpl(JTabbedPane.java:599)
  at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(JTabbedPane.java:574)
  at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI$Handler.mousePressed(BasicTabbedPaneUI.java:3628)
  at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTabbedPaneUI$1.mousePressed(SynthTabbedPaneUI.java:279)
  at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:262)
  at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6264)
  at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
  at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6032)
  at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
  at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4235)
  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
  at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
  at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: For better help and sooner, consider posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I don't see how it there is any chance of being able to help given the information presented. Please remember, most of us cannot read minds. I second the recommendation for an sscce.

Comment: _is giving too many errors._ doesn't help us. You have to post the exact error messages and also a stacktrace. And also try to format your code nicely before posting.

Comment: We're volunteers and it takes quite a bit of effort to understand someone else's code. Please don't make it more difficult with terrible code formatting.

Comment: sorry guys im new here trying my best to format correctly

Comment: A key is your indentation which should be *consistent* throughout a block of code, not random. Have your code indent by 3-4 spaces and keep the same indentation throughout the block.

Comment: Edited. Please note the difference.

Comment: Which line is line 68 of Academic.java, the one throwing the NPE?

Comment: the problem really is me unable to get a value out of the 'AcademicBean' class for example 'bn.getEmail();' returns null, when it has been set values in the Academic class already i.e. 'bean.setEmail(...); '

Comment: I already told you one problem with your AcademicBean, that you're creating a new different one. Don't do that. Get the AcademicBean from the Academic object.

Comment: I got you, i realised now i had two beans. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild a***'d guess: You appear to have at least two completely unrelated academicBean objects (note that the class should be named **A**cademicBean), one in Academic, and one in MainMenu. I have a suspicion that they should be one and the same.

Perhaps MainMenu should have:

```
academicBean bn = ac.getAcademicBean();
```

and Academic have:

```
public academicBean getAcademicBean() {
   return bean;
}
```

so that MainMenu can extract Academic's bean making the bean variables refer to one and the same bean object.

Comment: @Hobercraft Full Of Eels what changes should i make at 'editProfile()'

Comment: @MuminAli: til you post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) it will be hard to guess. Please check the link to see what we're requesting you do.

Comment: @MuminAli: No, you omitted the exception name and cause, as well as an[sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Which is `line 68` in `Academic`?

Comment: pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM AcademicInfo where Email=? and Password=?");

Comment: isit a bad practice to directly obtain the profile info from database instead of from bean